# How can I access objects from a xaml that I create in cs code?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to access some objects that I create with cs (carousel pages with labels, listview and buttons) but I have not had success.

**Here reference this by saying that you can work with** `classId` **or** `styleId`**, but it does not make it very clear how to get the same:**
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/getting_started_with_xaml/

Here you can see the carousel pages

[image]

This is my cs code:

```
    private readonly List<AreaModel> _are = new List<AreaModel>();
    public  AreasModal()
    {
        Lista();
    }

    protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged()
    {
        base.OnCurrentPageChanged();
        var index = Children.IndexOf(CurrentPage);
    }

    private async void Lista() 
    { 
    var listareas = await App.NaturalezaManager.GetAreas();
        foreach (var Area in listareas) {

            var areas = new AreaModel
            {
                IdArea = Area.IdArea,
            NombreArea = Area.NombreArea
            };
            _are.Add(areas);
            Button boton = new Button 
            { 
                Text =  "Listo",                                            
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand

            };
            Children.Add(new ContentPage
            {

                Content = new StackLayout
                {

                    Children =
                    {

                        new StackLayout
                        {
                            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                            Children =
                            {
                                new StackLayout
                                {
                                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                                    Children =
                                    {
                                        new Label
                                        {
                                            Text = Area.NombreArea,
                                            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
                                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                                            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                new Switch
                                    {
                                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand
                                    }
                            }


                        },
                        new ListView
                        {
                            ItemsSource = listareas,
                            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                            {

                                Label nameLabel = new Label
                                {
                                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                                };
                                nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty,"NombreArea");
                                Switch switcher = new Switch
                                {
                                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand
                                };
                                return new ViewCell
                                {
                                    View = new StackLayout

                                    {
                                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                                        Children =
                                        {
                                            new StackLayout
                                            {
                                                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                                                Children =
                                                {
                                                    nameLabel
                                                }
                                            },
                                            switcher
                                        }


                                    }
                                };
                             })
                        },
                        boton

                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }
```

I have to access these objects from the "OnCurrentPageChanged" method but I have no idea how to do it, since if it were xaml code could be obtained with the property `x:Name`, in advance thanks for the help.

Comment: What objects are you trying to access? The `ContentPage` objects within the `CarouselPage` or the objects within `listareas`? And what do you want to do with the objects?

Comment: Hello, I have to access both, what I should do is load the listview according to the area that is in the contentpage label, but I have to send a parameter to find the items in the list, but I do not know how to Assign an id Property or a name to my label

Comment: Just move the declaration of your objects to a higher level, just like the `_are` variable. Then you will be able to access them anywhere in that scope.